# Proving Yeo-Johnson transform

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing

I am reading “A new family of power transformations to improve normality or symmetry” by Yeo and Johnson, but cannot go through the equation (3.1) where authors declare $l_n(\theta|x)=-\frac{n}{2}log(2\pi)-\frac{n}{2}log(\sigma^2)-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{\psi(\lambda, x_i)-\mu\}^2+(\lambda-1)\sum_{i=1}^n\{sgn(x_i)log(|x_i|+1)\}.$

Here, $l_n(\theta|x)$ is log likelihood, x are measured data, $\theta=(\lambda, \mu, \sigma^2)$, and $\psi$ is Yeo-Johnson power transform parameterized by $\lambda$. I understand every terms except the last one from their assumption that for some $\lambda$, transformed observations would follow normal distribution. However, where does the last term come from?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The last term comes from the jacobian of your transformation.

You likelihood is

$$
\mathbb{P}(x_i | \lambda, \mu, \sigma) = \mathbb{P}(\Psi_\lambda(x_i) | \lambda, \mu, \sigma)*\det[J(\Psi_\lambda(x_i), x_i)]
$$
where the last term is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix $J$ defined by

$$
J_{i,j} = \frac{\partial \Psi_\lambda(x_i)}{\partial x_j}
$$
This matrix is diagonal, so its derminant is the product of its diagonal terms. If you compute explicitly the contribution of this term in the loglikelihood, for the different values of $\lambda$ and $x$ ($x > 0$ and $ x < 0$), you see that it can always be rewritten as $(\lambda-1)*sgn(x_i)\log(|x_i|+1)$.